# How do I update my VirtualBox guest running Ubuntu 20.04 server to use https?

Tags: server, virtualbox, https

I am running an instance of Ubuntu 20.04 server in a VirtualBox guest machine.
I want to update the system to accept https connections.
This machine is a copy of a VPS machine running Ubuntu 18.04, The copy has been updated to 20.04 but without the Lets encrypt updates that are in the real live system.
I want to be able to test updates that I am preparing for the real machine in the VM.
Lets encrypt procedures require there to be an external access to the system, this is not possible in the VM.
Following various articles on how to install https fails because when accessed there is no CA to which the inserted certificate can be guaranteed by.
How can it be done?

Comment: You will want to [create a self-signed certificate](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04). So long as the VM is only accessed by you, this should solve your problem.

Comment: could you provide more details?

Comment: i have a self signed certificate but it does not work on my LAN as it has no referring CA